# One Alias to point to multiple IP addresses

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, load-balancing

The problem I have is the following:
I have distributed application (3 geographically spreader nodes), which on request returns large data sets. In order to reduce the network traffic, I need to direct the client request to the closest instance of the distributed application. 
I was thinking of several options, but for each of them I have the questions, which I would appreciate your opinions:

Option 1: Use DNS to resolve into multiple IP addresses. For example: 
- If I make call from the UK machine, to the server.copmany.com - DNS to resolve this into UK IP address of the system in question.
- If I make call from the US machine, to the server.copmany.com - DNS to resolve this into US IP address of the system in question.

**Question**: Is it possible to configure DNS for something like this?

Option 2: Use load balancer, which can resolve the IP address to the closest server.

**Question**: Although I think this is possible, what I can’t afford is the response to go back via Load Balancer, but directly to the calling system.

Option 3: Have you came across to any other solution for this sort of the problems?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Maxmind or Ip2location provides databases whcih u can use with ur application and some code changes needed in your application and it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks - I will look at this in more details. Not sure how this fits into the bigger picture and were exactly it sits in the network stack.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with option #1.

Dont know which DNS server you're using, but this can be done with BIND with GeoIP support, and multiple views for different users from different countries. Googling "BIND GeoIP" will get you a bunch of tutorials how to set it up.

Othewise, there are 3rd party services (keywords: "managed dns,geolocation") which offer this service.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. We use MS DNS integrated with Active Directory and my infrastructure guys are desparately waving they heads saying that there is nothing they can do to solve this problem, at least not on DNS level. Not to mention that MS DNS is defacto standard and that its replacement cannot be even conteplated.

Comment: Please tell us that the UK IPs in this scenario are private network. If they truly have Active Directory integrated DNS servers responding to internet traffic from the UK, they're doing something very wrong.

Comment: Yes. This is the global Private Network with 3 Data Centers in US/Europe/ASIA. I am not infrastrucutre guy myself, but someone who can influence the solutions on application level. Can you elaborate your last statement bit more, please? Thanks!

Comment: @Mike Internet facing DNS servers that pass traffic to your domain controllers are considered to be a huge security risk. It sounds like that doesn't apply here.

Comment: I'd also like to say that your infrastructure guys are wrong about their DNS servers having to be replaced. DNS servers can be configured to forward requests for specific domains or subdomains to different DNS servers. (such as mulaz's suggested BIND servers)

Answer (score 0):

Via DNS

1. I know for certain Bind supports views because I've used t hem before.  Other servers may as well.  With a view you serve whatever zone information you like based upon the requesting IP address - http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html
2. Use round-robin DNS to resolv one of three IPS.  This would not care where the request came from however

I found this googling (http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/services/global-traffic-director/) - Maybe you'll find it interesting

Answer (score 0):

If it's just HTTP you could serve a 301 to the appropriate site instead of having to do geo-DNS which is probably simpler.

One thing that probably won't work well is anycast, which although it might look good, can't (without significant assistance) handle cases where a client flips between nodes.